# Fetch API, custom request headers, CORS, and cross-origin redirects

Tags: http, cors, fetch-api, preflight

I need to make an HTTP GET request with custom request headers in-browser and process the result as it streams in.  The Fetch API is ideal for this:

```js
fetch('https://example.com/resource', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-Brad-Test': 'true'
  },
  cache: 'no-store',
  mode: 'cors'
}).then((res) => {
  const reader = res.body.getReader();
  // etc.
});
```

This works quite well.  Since there are custom headers, the browser pre-flights the request with an OPTIONS request to `/resource`.  I have configured my server to respond with a `204 No Content` and the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Range, If-Range, X-Brad-Test
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The browser is happy with this, then makes a GET request, the server returns a `200 OK` with the data, and the browser allows me to access the response headers and body.

The problem comes in when there is a redirect.  The `OPTIONS` request succeeds with the `204 No Content` and the same headers as before.  The browser makes the correct `GET` request, and on the server I send a `302` with a `Location:` header.  Chrome throws the following error:

> Fetch API cannot load https://example.com/resource. Redirect from 'https://example.com/resource' to 'http://some-other-origin/resource' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

This was unexpected, and seems nonsensical to me.  I expected the browser to follow the redirect, and do another pre-flight request for this new location, but it didn't do that.

Stranger still is that I can sort of hack around this client-side.  I can make an HTTP request without my custom header, figure out where I ended up after redirects by looking at the Response object, then make a second request at the new target with my custom headers.  This doesn't work in all cases of course, and I'd rather not rely on this hack.  I'd rather find a proper way.

Two Questions:

- What is the proper way to allow the client to follow redirects?  Is there some sort of `Access-Control-*` header I can use?
- Why does this restriction exist?  What security issue is prevented by not following and running pre-flight on the followed URL?

Comment: Your 302 response includes an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header?

Comment: OK I vaguely recall past discussion of this and will spend some time looking back at the spec and talking to the editor and implementors to see if I can get somebody to post an answer here (or will post one myself if I can manage to get it figured out on my own first).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229 and https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/204

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917489/http-302-redirect-to-a-cors-request-is-dropped-by-browsers/30192374
This issue has actually been spotted a really long time ago (3+ years).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supporting redirects to requests that require a preflight is very recent change to Fetch (which defines CORS).

https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commit/0d9a4db8bc02251cc9e391543bb3c1322fb882f2

I believe some implementations have started adjusting their implementations, but this will take some time to reach everyone.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know the reasoning behind this restriction in the first place?  Was it simply an error or an edge case?  Also, are there any better workarounds then what I have proposed in the question?

Comment: We didn't want to figure out the processing model at the time, not realizing that blocking on redirects was actually more complicated. It was a mistake and it took a long time to correct since nobody really complained about it.

(Cannot think of a better workaround.)

Comment: Is there any new progress about this?

Comment: Not much I think, someone needs to get around to writing tests and poke browsers again. It's on my list, but it's a long list sadly.

Comment: @Anne Greetings from 2018!  Any update by chance?  Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell the only holdout is Firefox, which is tracked at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1346749. See https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/204#issuecomment-286088120 for issues against other browsers.

Comment: It looks like these fixes only apply to preflighted requests -- any insight on [my question about simple redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518370/transparent-movement-of-cors-enabled-resources-with-cross-origin-redirect)?

Comment: @Anne Still the CORS spec says fail incase of redirect for a request with preflight. https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight.