# Transparent movement of CORS-enabled resources with cross-origin redirect

Tags: cors, fetch-api

I want to access a REST service that's protected by CAS running on a different domain.  This means I need to make a request to a CAS login endpoint and have it redirect me to the destination service.  There are dozens of questions here about *why* CORS redirects fail, but I have yet to find any answer about *how* to actually make it work.

I found some [W3C guidance for dealing with CORS](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/#identify-yourself-and-get-permission-simple-request-read-permissions) that includes a dedicated aside on the topic:

> To make possible transparent movement of CORS-enabled resources accessed via simple requests requires work and coordination by servers. For example, a resource at https://old.example.com/resource might respond to a CORS request with credentals with a redirect to https://new.example.com/resource?originalOrigin=...&credential=... which would carry the authority to access the resource in the URL parameter instead of the Cookie and Origin headers. The server at https://new.example.com would need custom logic to recognize and authenticate these parameters and perform appropriate authorization before returning Access-Control-Allow- headers to the user agent.

I control the container for both services plus the client code, so I should be able to do this (right?), but I don't think what's described in that document is actually possible.  The login endpoint already is able to redirect with a one-time credential token (that's how CAS works), so it should be easy.

As the text says, the redirector (`old.example.com` in the above) should be requested with credentials.  But, if I call `fetch(url, {credentials:"include"})`, credentials will also be included when following the redirect (`new.example.com`, in the above).  Because I'm telling `fetch` to include credentials, the final URL loaded by the browser must send a matching ACA-Origin header, but because it's the target of a redirect, the origin of the second request will be `null`.

To make the W3C-suggested workflow possible, I'd need to be able to tell the browser to send credentials to `old.example.com` but once it redirects you to `new.example.com`, request it without credentials / in no-cors mode.  As far as I know that's not possible -- the initial request and all following redirects get the same fetch options.  Am I missing something?  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything. You'd need to update all callers if you don't want to allow credentialed requests on the new location.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: I just want to do what the W3C piece suggests, which is to let the "old" service authenticate via cookies but the "new" service authenticate via query-parameter token.  I don't see how to do both things in a single `fetch` call.  Would a more explicit example help?

Comment: You're not unclear; you're correct that it's not possible. An exception of sorts would be if `new.example.com` didn't get any cookies to begin with. The browser could then still make "credentialed" requests, but they just wouldn't include any cookies. The server would still have to reply as if a credentialed request was made though.

Comment: So, the W3C guidance is wrong, and the approach they're suggesting to address this need ("transparent movement of CORS-enabled resources") is in fact impossible on the current web?  Am I the only person trying to use cross-origin CAS or something?  I feel like I have to be missing something big, but for the life of me I can't tell what it is. Also: I don't think I understand what you mean by "update all callers" in this context, since it's one call that (automatically, out of my control) follows server redirects.