# Determine source of an <audio> tag in JavaScript after the stream redirects

Tags: javascript, html, audio-streaming

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="aPlayer" name="media" src="https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls >
        </video>
        <br/>
        <input id="srcCheck" type="button" value="Check aPlayer.src value" onclick="alert(aPlayer.src);">
    </body>
</html>
```

When loading the above page, the source https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3 redirects to:
https://assets.kerkdienstgemist.nl/static/no_broadcast-c0e1ed59.mp3. No problem with that.

When clicking the button before clicking play, the initial url is displayed. Still good. But when you click the button after you clicked play, still shows the same url, although it was redirected to a new location and playing the stream.

To demonstrate that the url redirects, click on the link: https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3 and you will see that it changes in the browser address bar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From where will you run this code? From said domain `kerkdienstgemist.nl` or from an other one?

Comment: From another from another domain.

Comment: Then you're stuck.

Comment: @Kaiido Don't be so pessimistic.

Comment: @SytzeVisser You should be able to use a service worker for this task.

Comment: @Brad ServiceWorkers are able to bypass cross-origin resource sharing? You are not allowed to follow a cross origin redirect.

Comment: @Kaiido Who said anything about having a CORS issue here?  If the response headers are set up correctly, this is fine.  Also, it's entirely possible to follow a cross-origin redirect.  Worst case scenario, by going hop-by-hop with your requests.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40580913/362536

Comment: @Brad OP said in #comment2 to which my comment was responding. And what Anne pointed to is how to respond to a preflight request, i.e when CORS are satisfied. Here the server OP is fetching from doesn't accept preflight requests, so all you'll ever get is an opaque response. I'm not pessimist, they're stuck.

Comment: @Kaiido There's no reason the server cannot be reconfigured.

Comment: @Brad maybe the fact they obviously don't own all the servers they want to run this code against? Otherwise the answer would be `if(src==='https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3') src="https://assets.kerkdienstgemist.nl/static/no_broadcast-c0e1ed59.mp3"`.... Why don't you want to accept that what they are trying to do is against the cross-origin policies, and that if they ever succeed to find a front-end solution to it, it would be a bug. Of course, they could query from a proxy server that won't be subject to cors, but the question is tagged javascript.

Comment: @Kaiido There's nothing obvious about the ownership of the server being redirected to.  Why don't you want to accept the fact that your absolutist nonsense answer, "then you're stuck", may not be the only answer?  There isn't enough information here to make that claim, nor is there enough information to provide a solution as-is.  That's why I left a comment with a possible direction towards a potential solution.  Furthermore,  I don't see how a solution to this problem would be a bug.

Comment: @Brad we've got enough information to know that 1. OP is trying to find a flexible solution that would work on any website. 2. OP can't own all the servers in the world. Your potential solution using ServiceWorkers is non-sense. If a ServiceWorker is able to see the redirect clearly, then all that's needed is `fetch(url, {method:'HEAD'}).then(r=>r.url);` no need for a service worker. You are giving non-sensical leads to nowhere while once again, if you are ever able to circumvent cross-origin policies from front-end, then please file a bug report to the UA you made it with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182553/discussion-between-kaiido-and-brad).

Comment: @Kaiido You're misunderstanding what I'm proposing.  I'm suggesting intercepting that media request with a worker and using `fetch()` to actually make the request, and deal with following the redirects in client-side code.  I'm not suggesting circumventing cross-origin policy at all.  Obviously, the server needs to be configured to support CORS.  If the person who wrote this question would provide some additional details, I'll write a full answer that you can nitpick and rant at, instead of my intentionally-vague one-sentence original comment RE:service workers.

Comment: @Brad, But as I said ServiceWorkers would help in no way here. There are only 2 cases: **1.** CORS compliant => `fetch().then(r=>r.url)` is enough, **2.** not CORS friendly => *"You're stuck"*. My first comment determined exactly this. And we are in **2.**.

Comment: @Kaiido The reply to your first comment determined nothing about this person's ability to change the server configuration.  I'm happy you agree that this can be solved with usage of the Fetch API.  And yes, of course, you could add some code to handle it directly.  I'm proposing making this all a bit nicer with the worker, that's all.

Comment: Hey guys, what a lively discussion! I am learning a lot! So here is some more information: 
What I really need to do it to determine if the redirected url is: https://assets.kerkdienstgemist.nl/static/no_broadcast-c0e1ed59.mp3. It wil indicate to me that the resource I requested (https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3) is not available. 

Never heard of ServiceWorkers, but looking at what it does, it might just work.

Also looking at using cURL in php server side to get the headers and determine if a HTTP302 is present and then check for the redirected URL.

Comment: And that is what i did now. I make an AJAX call to an php script calling a cURL library to request the headers only, and when a 302 redirect is returned, I can check where the url was redirected to. Done! Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's **NOT** possible to detect a redirect with JavaScript because the src property of the current DOM will remain the same regardless of any redirect.

Even I tried with creating a player using code and tried my luck if we can see the src after video is redirected.

```
<input id="srcCheck" type="button" value="Check aPlayer.src value" onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
        var x = document.createElement("VIDEO");
        x.setAttribute("id", "aPlayer");
        x.setAttribute("src", "https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3");
        x.setAttribute("width", "320");
        x.setAttribute("height", "240");
        x.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        document.body.appendChild(x);

    function myFunction() {
            var t = document.getElementById("aPlayer");
            console.log(t.src);
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: It is possible, under some conditions. Also, better use currentSrc at getting than src.

Comment: May be, but in this case currentSrc: "https://kerkdienstgemist.nl/streams/75528.mp3" is still the same as src.

Comment: Yes I know, we're not yet in the "some conditions" I mentioned, and currentSrc is just a general advice that I find particularly on topic under an answer about retrieving the current source of a MediaElement.

Comment: I hope that you are absolutely wrong!  But thanks for attempting to solve the problem.