# Avoid CORS when using nginx to redirect to S3

Tags: nginx, service-worker

I'm setting up a service worker for my site (site.foo.co) which is behind nginx.

All my assets live on my S3 server (files.foo.co).

To avoid caching opaque requests (in Chrome), the service worker needs the assets to be from the same origin.

To do that, I assume the easiest approach is to have all asset requests go to nginx, which then redirects to S3.
The problem is the browser still treats redirects as cors requests.

How can I configure nginx to proxy requests to S3 & have the browser treat it like a sameorigin request?

My attempt below successfully redirects the request, but it doesn't avoid cors.

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    proxy_pass https://files.foo.co;
    rewrite ([^/]*$) https://files.foo.co/$1;
}
```

How can I change my config to fix this? Is there another approach that might be better?

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/40580913/362536  Why not just put your service worker in your bucket?

Comment: So it's a big in Chrome's fetch implementation? Chrome also disallows the service worker to come from a redirect