# Nginx load balancer error when 302 is used

Tags: nginx, cors, load-balancing

I've an nginx container used as load balancer, for a streaming DASH-based service.There are also 3 VM used as upstream servers.
This is nginx config file:

```
upstream cdn-audio {
        server 192.168.99.103:9500;
        server 192.168.99.104:9500;
        server 192.168.99.105:9500;
   }

upstream cdn-video {

        server 192.168.99.103:9500;
        server 192.168.99.104:9500;
        server 192.168.99.105:9500;
    }


server {

listen 80;
server_name 172.17.0.1;
access_log /var/log/nginx/acces.log main;

location = /LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4 {

#           proxy_pass http://192.168.99.103:9500;

# proxy_pass http://cdn-audio/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4;
add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
add_header Host $host;
if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        add_header Host $host;
        return 200;
    }

       return 302 $scheme://cdn-audio/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4;

        }

location = /LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4 {

add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
#  proxy_pass http://cdn-audio/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4;
add_header Host $host;


if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' ;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        add_header Host $host;
        return 200;
}


#       proxy_pass http://cdn-video$request_uri;

#       proxy_pass http://192.168.99.103:9500;

       return 302 $scheme://cdn-video/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4;
#       add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;

        }

   }
```

From an html page hosted in another container ( a frontend container), first there is a HTTP OPTIONS request to :/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4 and :/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4, because of cross site origin.
Then the response header is shown in the config code.

Then, when i try to redirect request to one of my three upstream server, there is an error:

- XMLHttpRequest cannot load
  http: // localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4. Redirect from
  'http: // localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4' to
  'http: // cdn-video/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4' has been blocked by
  CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to
  follow cross-origin redirect.
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load
  http: // localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4. Redirect from
  'http: // localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4' to
  'http: // cdn-audio/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4' has been blocked by
  CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to
  follow cross-origin redirect.

Please note that i made

```
curl -I -X OPTIONS http://192.168.99.103:9500/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4
```

This is response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.11.8
Date: Wed, 25 Jan 2017 16:31:28 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you understand why your browser is sending the OPTIONS preflight request instead of just sending the actual request directly? That normally only happens if you adding custom headers to the request or if you are setting the content-type of the request to a particular value. It could be that you could avoid the OPTIONS preflight just by making some adjustments to your request (e.g., removing from it any unnecessary headers that may be getting added).

Comment: This is my architecture: i've a frontend html+js in one container; load balancer container; N VM as CDN. First, i point with frontend html to l.b: this causes a OPTIONS preflight request, because this is a cross site origin request. If, in l.b., i use proxy_pass directive (insted of return 302 etc), after this first OPTIONS request, i can access to the contents via HTTP GET. If i use return 302 etc, after this HTTP OPTIONS (which response is correct), i see, from browser's network console, a lot of GET with 302 response.. and error i posted above. This error is caused by return 302, i think.

Comment: The fact it’s a cross-site request isn’t what causes the OPTIONS to be sent. [Lots of cross-site requests do not cause an OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests). What triggers the OPTIONS to be sent is the specific nature of the particular request you’re sending: If it contains headers other than those defined as [CORS-safelisted request-headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), only then will the OPTIONS be sent. So you may be able to avoid the OPTIONS by removing some headers from the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx configuration is returning a 302 to the browser.

In other words, you're trying to redirect requests from "localhost" to "cdn-video" which (unless you've configured local DNS or hosts file mapping) won't resolve in your browser.

You should also add the CORS methods header to your nginx config

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

I'd suggest simplifying your nginx config to something along the lines of (untested):

```
upstream cdn-audio {
  least_conn;
  server 192.168.99.103:9500;
  server 192.168.99.104:9500;
  server 192.168.99.105:9500;
}

upstream cdn-video {
  least_conn;
  server 192.168.99.103:9500;
  server 192.168.99.104:9500;
  server 192.168.99.105:9500;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 172.17.0.1;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/acces.log main;

  location /audio/ {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,Range";
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
      add_header Content-Length 0;
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      add_header Host $host;
      return 200;
    }

    proxy_pass http://cdn-audio; # expects the audio files to be in a "audio" folder on the upstream box
    add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
    add_header Host $host;
  }

  location /video/ {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' ;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization,Range";
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
      add_header Content-Length 0;
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      add_header Host $host;
      return 200;
    }

    proxy_pass http://cdn-video; # expects the video files to be in a "video" folder on the upstream box
    add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
    add_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @justcompile. I've added this line, and also allow origin * . CORS is supported. But still same error.

Comment: i don't want proxy_pass, but a redirect approach, using 302 moved temporarely. This because this load balancer has upstream servers that forms a CDN, and so using proxy_pass directive it could be a bottleneck.

Comment: By bottleneck do you mean that 1 upstream server would potentially get more requests than another? You could add the "least_conn" directive to your upstream definitions so that nginx sends traffic to the server with the least number of connections. I'll amend the example (whether I'm understanding correctly or not) :)

Comment: my bottleneck now is load balancer because: if there are i.e. 100, 1000 http request from these contents, load balancer is a bottleneck. My goal is configuring load balancer with a redirect approach: for example, if there are 200 browser that points to the load balancer (l.b.) contents, the load balancer is under a huge amount of load. For avoiding this problem, i want use a redirect approach: once a browser points to l.b, it tells to browser "redirect to upstream 192.168.99.103:9500 or 192.168.99.104:9500"; then browser get resource to 192.168.99.103:9500, for example.

Comment: I understand. Well then my point about the browser not knowing what "cdn-video" is relevant. Also make sure that your servers also return the cors headers as once you've redirected, those headers will need to exist on the response from the redirected location

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my first post, there is output of curl -I -X OPTIONS http://192.168.99.103:9500/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4 , where 192,168.99.103 is one of my upstream server. It's enabled to CORS. I really don't know how to solve the problem

Comment: What about my point about the browser not resolving "cdn-audio"? If you change the 302 domain from cdn-audio to one of the ip addresses of your upstreams, do you still get CORS errors?

Comment: cannot try now, i don't have access to that computer right now. I'll response u in about 10h. Thanks for support.

Comment: i've tried to redirect directly to one of my upstream server, but still same error. This is strange, because you can see, in my first post, a correct CORS-enabled response to an OPTIONS request to upstream server

Comment: Have you added the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header to the upstream servers too?

Answer (score 0):

@sideshowbarker These are the request and response header, in case of proxy_pass and redirect 302.

```
header options + get chunk with proxy pass:

OPTIONS

General

Request URL:http://localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9200

Response Headers

view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Thu, 26 Jan 2017 08:41:52 GMT
Host:localhost
Server:nginx/1.11.6

Request Headers

view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:range
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9200
Origin:http://localhost:8400
Referer:http://localhost:8400/shaka-player-master/demo/homepage.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36


GET

General

Request URL:http://localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:206 Partial Content
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9200

Response Headers

view source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Range
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:692
Content-Range:bytes 1040-1731/6797033
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Thu, 26 Jan 2017 08:41:52 GMT
ETag:W/"6797033-1484728792000"
Host:localhost
Last-Modified:Wed, 18 Jan 2017 08:39:52 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.6
X-Proxy-Cache:MISS
X-Upstream:192.168.99.103:9500

Request Headers

view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9200
Origin:http://localhost:8400
Range:bytes=1040-1731
Referer:http://localhost:8400/shaka-player-master/demo/homepage.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36




header options and get chunk with redirect:

OPTIONS:

General

Request URL:http://localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9200

Response Headers

view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Thu, 26 Jan 2017 08:52:22 GMT
Host:localhost
Server:nginx/1.11.6

Request Headers

view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:range
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9200
Origin:http://localhost:8400
Referer:http://localhost:8400/shaka-player-master/demo/homepage.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

GET

General

Request URL:http://localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9200

Response Headers

view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:161
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 26 Jan 2017 08:52:22 GMT
Host:localhost
Location:http://cdn-video/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4
Server:nginx/1.11.6

Request Headers

view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9200
Origin:http://localhost:8400
Range:bytes=1136-1767
Referer:http://localhost:8400/shaka-player-master/demo/homepage.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

Initiator = http://localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4  ; type= xhr

SECOND GET:

General

Request URL:http://localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9200

Response Headers

view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:161
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 26 Jan 2017 08:52:22 GMT
Host:localhost
Location:http://cdn-video/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4
Server:nginx/1.11.6

Request Headers

view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9200
Origin:http://localhost:8400
Range:bytes=1136-1767
Referer:http://localhost:8400/shaka-player-master/demo/homepage.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36


Initiator = "other"; type= text/html.
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using google canary.

With canary, it works if i redirect content directly to one of my three upstream server.
If i redirect to upstream name (i.e. cdn-audio(or video)) the browser cannot resolve name.

I've heard about lua-upstream-module for nginx, can someone help me?