# HTTP Preflight Check - When should a redirect response happen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, redirect

We've fixed the problem on a weird edge-case we have, but I'd really like clear up what the correct setup (if there is one) should be. The scenario is:

1. We have an endpoint which we hit - if opened directly in a browser
   it redirects to the actual resource, which is intended.
2. On a separate site we call the endpoint via through an AJAX call (specifically angular $HTTP, but you can think of it as an XMLHttpRequest).
3. The call starts the HTTP/GET process - but it determines an OPTIONS/pre-flight request is needed.
4. The server responds with a redirect to the actual resource
5. On the client $HTTP interprets this as a  pre-flight failure as it isn't a 200/OK response.

I guess the question is: should the server respond with a 200 on the OPTIONS request at step 4, then respond with the redirect when the actual GET happens, or is the redirect legitimate, and the client side should then transfer the request to the actual endpoint at step 5. If the latter I'd assume the functionality would be baked in, but you know what happens when you assume....

I've had a look around a few places, the http 1.1 spec only really defines an OK response, not what a correct failure looks like: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.2

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917489/http-302-redirect-to-a-cors-request-is-dropped-by-browsers) answer helpful? The solution proposed is to use a custom status code and configure your client to use it for the redirect.

Comment: How can it do a 200 and a redirect at the same time? I'm confused.

Comment: @KarlReid That's spot on, even thought the questioner has the "reverse" problem, in that they get a 200 on the OPTIONS request, then the 30x. The answer is in the linked document: https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0  : 
"If the [OPTIONS] response has an HTTP status code that is not in the 2xx range
Apply the network error steps."

So I guess it's a client side responsiblity!

Comment: @Rob - I don't think it is the same  time - unless I've misread the question. I think the browser is breaking the GET request into and initial [pre-flight] OPTIONS request, then when that gets a response of 200/OK it makes the actual GET.